# Create users based on a text file using Bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

So, I have a text file that is organized like this

```
<username>:<fullname>:<usergroups>
```

I need to create a new user for each line and put them into their groups. I am stuck with trying to set `username` into a variable to use with `useradd`. I have tried using `cut` but it needs a file name, I can't just pass it a line.

Here is what I currently have:

```
#! /bin/bash
linesNum=1 
while read line
do
  echo
  name=$( cut -d ":" -f1 $( line ) )
  ((lineNum+=1))
done < "users.txt"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$(line)` is really wrong, it will consider `line` as a command, what you want is rather `"$line"` or `"${line}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read username fullname usergroups
do
    useradd -G $usergroups -c "$fullname" $username
done < users.txt
```

`fullname` is the only string that should contains whitespace (hence the quotes),  A list of `usergroups` should be separated from the next by a comma, with no intervening whitespace (so no quotes on that argument) and your `username` should not contain whitespace either.

### Upate:

To get the list of `usergroups` to create first you can do this...

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read username fullname usergroups
do
    echo $usergroups >> allgrouplist.txt
done < users.txt

while IFS=, read group
do
   echo $group >> groups.txt
done < allgrouplist.txt

sort -u groups.txt | while read group
do
   groupadd $group
done
```

This is a bit long winded, and could be compacted to avoid the use of the additional files `allgrouplist.txt` and `groups.txt` but I wanted to make this easy to read. For reference here's a more compact version.

```
sort -u < $(
       echo $(while IFS=: read a b groups; do echo $groups; done < users.txt )
      | while IFS=, read group; do echo $group; done ) 
| while read group
do
       groupadd $group
done
```

<sub>(I screwed the compact version up a bit at first, it should be fine now, but please note I haven't tested this!)</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to do this without adding the user groups before hand?
Could I loop through usergroups and create each one before I do useradd?

Also: What exactly does IFS=: do? Does it set the field seperator to : ?

Comment: @amazinghorse24 the [bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) explains the special variables :-)

Comment: IFS is the standard field separator environment var. You could do the group adding as a separate operation yes, use `usermod -g $usergroups $username`.

Comment: @amazinghorse: `$IFS` is the input field separator; it's used by the shell to split the input for various things, such as `read`. You could do a similar thing with the value of `$usergroups`, except you pass `-d ','` to `read` to split by commas instead of newlines.

Comment: I'll update the answer to show how you'd add all the usergroups.

Comment: Thanks! This has been a big help.

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=: while read username fullname usergroups
do
  useradd -G "$usergroups" -c "$fullname" "$username"
done < users.txt
```